# Add Web API To .Net Core Console Application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

There is a simple dotnetcore console app project that I want to add an api controller class on it.I searched  too much and I had wild goose chase.somebody says you should use `OwinSelfHost` but when I would install that I see this message on NuGet package manager:

Nuget Package error -

```
this package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Why are you adding api controller on console application. Instead you can add new webapi project and create your api controller in it. Then you can consume api in console project

Comment: you mean I should add a web api project and refrence it by console project

Comment: asp.net core applications are technically already console applications. You shouldn't need to use the OwinSelfHost package